# Match '$GPGGA' expression

Tags: c#, regex, expression, match

I have a GPS device that outputs multiple separate strings every 1 second, like this(few seconds worth of data):

```
$GPGGA,021225.000,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,1,14,0.73,-5.2,M,41.5,M,,*44
$GNRMC,021225.000,A,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,0.00,324.63,041017,,,A*70
$GPVTG,324.63,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,A*3D
$GPGGA,021226.000,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,1,14,0.73,-5.2,M,41.5,M,,*47
$GNRMC,021226.000,A,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,0.00,324.63,041017,,,A*73
$GPVTG,324.63,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,A*3D
$GPGGA,021227.000,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,1,14,0.73,-5.2,M,41.5,M,,*46
$GNRMC,021227.000,A,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,0.00,324.63,041017,,,A*72
$GPVTG,324.63,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,A*3D
```

My objective is simple, I only need the (whole) string starting in $GPGGA. So instead, of seeing all the above strings, I simply need:

```
$GPGGA,021225.000,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,1,14,0.73,-5.2,M,41.5,M,,*44
$GPGGA,021226.000,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,1,14,0.73,-5.2,M,41.5,M,,*47
$GPGGA,021227.000,5425.7163,N,01341.7347,E,1,14,0.73,-5.2,M,41.5,M,,*46
```

Simples, right?!

For reference, this is the code I am using:

```
string numbers = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
var ismatch = Regex.Match(numbers, @"");

if (ismatch.Success)
{
    tbData.AppendText(numbers);
}
else
{
    tbData.AppendText("Invalid");
}
```

I am quite sure the code is working okay, because with @"" it returns all the strings (in the textbox in the UI) without showing 'Invalid' instead.

I've tried a million different expressions, including very simple ones but I can't get a handle for the language.

So for the Regex geniuses out there, could you enlighten me to what expression will work for '$GPGGA.......' ?

Comment: I use following msdn website for reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Comment: You should not use regex in this case.  Regex is not as efficient as straight string methods.  In this case all you need is string startswith("$GPGGA").  There are lots of place regex should be used.  This is not one of them.

Comment: @jdweng You should post that as an alternative answer :-)

Comment: It is not the alternate answer, it is the right answer.  Regex in this case should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a special character in RegEx. You need to escape it to match it (`\$`).

So something like this should work:

```
var ismatch = Regex.Match(numbers, @"^(\$GPGGA,.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Let's break this down:

- `^` - Match the start of the input
- `(` - Start of a capture group
- `\$GPGGA,` - Match this specific text (note the escaped $)
- `.*` - Match everything else
- `)` - End of the capture group
- `$` - End of the input

In order to get capture groups for each line starting with $GPGGA, I had to enable Multiline (`RegexOptions.Multiline`).

FYI, I often use [this site](http://regexstorm.net/tester) for testing Regular Expressions. Their reference page is also helpful.

I've put together a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TvaWYg) for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Interesting, it works in the fiddle, but does not work for the real thing!

Comment: Even if I leave it empty (just using @"") it does not append the text box anymore.  In my original code, it can at least do that

Comment: I just tried my original code (as above) but with @"^(\$GPGGA,.*)$" as recommended. Also does not work. Could it be I have an issue the format like strings, var, or something? Maybe thats a silly question - I'm just a novice!

Comment: @Jon Can you create a fiddle so that I can see what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer does not use Rengex, but it works, and took me a while to make sure it contain no error.

```
//assume you have your string from Serial Port (COM)
string[] strArr = data.Split('$'); //split different GPS string
for (int j = 0; j < strArr.Length; j++)
{
    string strTemp = strArr[j];
    debug = strTemp;
    string[] lineArr = strTemp.Split(',');
    if (lineArr[0] == "GPGGA")
    {
        try
        {
            //Latitude
            if (lineArr.Length >= 7 && lineArr[2] != "")
            {
                //Latitude
                double converted = Convert.ToDouble(lineArr[2]) / 100;
                string[] lat = converted.ToString().Split('.');
                string altered = lat[1] + "000000000000000000000000";
                double me = Convert.ToDouble(lat[0].ToString()) + ((Convert.ToDouble(altered.Substring(0, 6)) / 60)) / 10000;
                Latitude = lineArr[3].ToString() + me.ToString();
                //Longitude
                double converted1 = Convert.ToDouble(lineArr[4]) / 100;
                string[] lon = converted.ToString().Split('.');
                string altered1 = lon[1] + "000000000000000000000000";
                double me1 = Convert.ToDouble(lon[0].ToString()) + ((Convert.ToDouble(altered1.Substring(0, 6)) / 60)) / 10000;
                Longitude = lineArr[5].ToString() + me1.ToString();
                //Time
                string timeMinAndSec = lineArr[1][0].ToString() + lineArr[1][1].ToString();
                //Altitude
                if (lineArr.Length >= 10)
                { 
                    Altitude = lineArr[9].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```